# Picking API level for Android app in Eclipse and manifest

Tags: android, api, eclipse-adt

I am not fully certain that I am not making any mistakes when setting API level when developing under Eclipse so here are some examples which I am not 100% certain about.

1. When developing Android app in Eclipse I always set BuildProjectTarget under Eclipse and      android:targetSdkVersion in the manifest to the latest available Android version. Is this practice correct? NOTE:I do set android:minSdkVersion according to the project (usually value is 10)
2. I know that doing the above will trigger Eclipse warning about unsupported API when using something not available in version under android:minSdkVersion (for example using fragments without support library) are there any examples when these shouldn't be trusted and what will happen if you build the project using Gradle/Ant script or manually?
3. What would happen if I set BuildProjectTarget and android:targetSdkVersion to for example 16 and then use some deprecated API like WebView setCertificate() (which was deprecated in API level 17). Will this method work on all devices or just those up to Android 4.1, will it crash the app or just be ignored?
4. I know that Eclipse uses Java library android.jar from SDK/platforms folder and that when on the device app links to that library stored on device but what I don't get is are there multiple versions of this library on android phones or just one (the latest for that android version) ? Also does a version of framework.jar play a role in this?
5. What happens with the libraries when you use something like google_play_services? Are these packed into the apk or reference the library that is already on the device? I know that when you use Facebook sdk the jar gets packed into apk but don't know are these google libraries different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When developing Android app in Eclipse I always set BuildProjectTarget under Eclipse and android:targetSdkVersion in the manifest to the latest available Android version. Is this practice correct? NOTE:I do set android:minSdkVersion according to the project (usually value is 10)

**Yes. That way you ensure you're always using the latest build sdk.**

> I know that doing the above will trigger Eclipse warning about unsupported API when using something not available in version under android:minSdkVersion (for example using fragments without support library) are there any examples when these shouldn't be trusted and what will happen if you build the project using Gradle/Ant script or manually?

**Just make sure that older devices will not get to that part of the code, using `Build.Version.SDK_INT`. This will give you the current SDK of the device.**

> What would happen if I set BuildProjectTarget and android:targetSdkVersion to for example 16 and then use some deprecated API like WebView setCertificate() (which was deprecated in API level 17). Will this method work on all devices or just those up to Android 4.1, will it crash the app or just be ignored?

**Deprecated methods will continue to work, but better alternatives are available. When you have the option to use that better alternative, use it. When you're supporting devices that don't have this alternative yet due to older versions, continue using the deprecated method. You might have to do some `if else` branching based upon the `Build.Version.SDK_INT` value.**

> I know that Eclipse uses Java library android.jar from SDK/platforms folder and that when on the device app links to that library stored on device but what I don't get is are there multiple versions of this library on android phones or just one (the latest for that android version) ? Also does a version of framework.jar play a role in this?

**The newer devices contain the code of the older devices. Therefore it is not necessary to keep references to other versions.**

> What happens with the libraries when you use something like google_play_services? Are these packed into the apk or reference the library that is already on the device? I know that when you use Facebook sdk the jar gets packed into apk but don't know are these google libraries different?

**The class files in the jar will be packaged in the .apk. The Google Play Services on the device communicates with your app using those classes.**

Comment: Thank you for response. This answer does clear some things, especially the answer to 5. I only don't get the "The newer devices contain the code of the older devices. Therefore it is not necessary to keep references to other versions." does this mean that new devices have all older android.jar libraries on them (something like Windows Side-by-side assembly) ? What happens if I use method that was removed from API in newer versions?

Comment: PS.I do use branching based upon the Build.Version.SDK_INT sometimes but only to make something available on devices with older android version (some kind of fall-back)

Comment: Methods are *added* to the existing code. Normally speaking, to ensure backwards compatibility, methods are not *removed* from the code in newer versions. Check for example the [difference between the TextView classes in Android 4.1 and 4.4](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/widget/TextView.java/?v=diff&id2=4.0.4_r2.1). You will see that no (public) code is removed, and only code is added.

Comment: I guessed that is the case but sometimes rarely they do remove methods. Do you happen to know why they write "This method doesn't do anything useful sometimes? It's like they remove method implementation and just keep empty brackets in order not to break the apps

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes this practice is correct and is done to ensure support for the latest android versions.
2. When you set a minSdkVersion, then that's thr lowest version of Android your app will support and compiling with ant/gradle will show errors ehen you will use methods introduced in newer api levels for an older one.
3. Deprecated means that another method has replaced this one and that this one will spon be removed from the Android source code, so developers are encouraged not to use them. But yes they will work until they remain in the source.
4. The android.jar is a dependency of the methods and stuff included in the android OS, stuff that you'd be able to call and no I don't think framework.jar plays a role in this.
5. All external libraries are referenced and added to the apk. BUT only some of the google ones, those that are not primary. (Take a look at the gapps packages, that'll give you some specifics. Link: http://goo.im/gapps)

I hope I got this right and helped you to understand.

Comment: Thank you for explanations. You didn't mention what will happen in case 2 if building without eclipse? 5.How do I know which libraries are primary and which are not?

Comment: Where do I find  gapps packages ?

Comment: You can download the latest one from hereou can download the latest one from here: http://goo.im/gapps